# Microwave Greenhouse

Tags: electromagnetism, waves

IR is trapped by greenhouses, but what about VHF/UHF radio waves, are these trapped by greenhouses?

Precisely, what is the mechanism which determines whether a wave is “trapped” or not?

Comment: Depends upon the material used to construct the greenhouse, i.e., whether or not you want to stop or pass IR. Regarding RF signals, they scatter off the ionosphere - the portion of the atmosphere which is electrical change - hence the name. Whether or not it's scattered depends upon the frequency of the RF signal. See "https://radiojove.gsfc.nasa.gov/education/educ/radio/tran-rec/exerc/iono.htm".

Answer (score 0):

It's not so much that IR is trapped in greenhouses -- the greenhouse glass isn't a one-way door for IR.  Rather, the glass is transparent to visible light (and near IR), but opaque in longer wavelengths.

So energy comes in as visible light and gets absorbed by the stuff inside the greenhouse, making it warmer.  That stuff then glows mostly in the longwave IR (at least you hope it's only longwave IR -- if it's hot enough to glow in the visible spectrum your plants may not grow as much as you'd hope).

It's that longwave IR -- which is energy that came *in* to the greenhouse as shorter-wavelength light -- that is trapped.

It is the fact that glass (and, I assume, plastic) is opaque in IR that traps the IR.  The greenhouse works because the covering is *not* opaque to shorter wavelengths*.

You could, in theory, make a greenhouse that would also trap RF and microwaves -- it would just take a covering that includes a conductive mesh that would let in short wavelengths but would appear as a solid conductor to micro- and longer waves.

* This is a factor** in why greenhouses aren't made of germanium or silicon (which are opaque to visible, but transparent to IR).

** OK, it's way way down on the list of why you may not want to make a greenhouse with silicon or germanium windows.  But still...